# FOS user /register path works in url but not as a path

Tags: php, twig, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm making a symfony project using Doctrine and FOS for user accounts.

I have the path `http://localhost:8000/register/` working properly and displaying my page.

However if I add it as a path in twig like this:
`<p><a href="{{ path('register') }}">No Account? Register here!</a></p>`

I get this error

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to >generate a URL for the named route "/register" as such route does not exist.").

I already have all the need info in my **routing.yml**

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register

fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile
```

What can be the issue here and how can I fix it?

Comment: I think the route name is called `fos_user_registration_register` (see `@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml`), so use `{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}`.

Comment: You have `fos_user_register` route name in your routing.yml.

Comment: @ccKep Could you post this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml` the route is named `fos_user_registration_register`.

So `{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}` should work.